# Push notification not displaying when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement Firebase Push Notification into my IOS app but cant figure out how to receive notifications when the app is in background.

I used print to display the notification, but it only prints the notification when the application is opened. If i send a notification when the application is background nothing happens but the messages are printed as soon as i reopened the app.

Below is my AppDelegate Code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    registerForPushNotifications(application)
    FIRApp.configure()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter
        .defaultCenter()
        .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotificaiton),
                     name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    sendNotification();

    print("===== didReceiveRemoteNotification ===== %@", userInfo)
}




func tokenRefreshNotificaiton(notification: NSNotification) {
    let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!
    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}
func sendNotification() {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    let dict:NSDictionary = ["ID" : "your ID goes here"]
    notification.userInfo = dict as! [String : String]
    notification.alertBody = "title"
    notification.alertAction = "Open"
    notification.fireDate = NSDate()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)


}


}
```

I have also added to my info.plist

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

This is the format of the message i am sending

```
{
  "to" : "",
  "notification" : {
  "body" : "",
  "title" : "",
},
  "content_available": true,
  "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that is a firebase payload (which gets turned by firebase into an apple payload). But the apple keyword in app payloads is content-available, not content_available.

Answer (score -1):

You can't receive the push notification data when your app close. You should store message to server than user reach to message from there

Comment: can i display the notification when the app is in background?

Comment: yes you can display push notification when your app is in background

Comment: can you please explain what i have to do to the application and the code above because it doesn't seem to be working. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Verify that Project settings and "Capabilities" are correctly configured[image]

Comment: yes is it configured correctly but still not working. Thanks.

Comment: Turn on the Background Fetch capability